# Expressing a probability in terms of cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to express $P(|X-X_n|>\epsilon)$  in  terms of the cdf of $X$ and $X_n$ but can't think of anything. Is it possible to achieve or am I wasting time? There are no extra assumptions on the sequence of real random variables $X_n$, nor on $X$, except that the sequence converges to $X$ in probability.

Comment: In terms of $X$ and any particular $X_n$, you have no assumptions at all except that they are random variables.  There is no way to express $P(|X - X_n| > \epsilon)$ in terms of the cdf's of $X$ and $X_n$ because it depends on their joint distribution, not just on the individual distributions.

Comment: You can't express it, but you can bound it...

Comment: But I rather want it to bound something else, since it will go to 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have in mind is that if $X_n\xrightarrow{P}X$ then $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ thus the limit CDF of the sequence $\{X_n\}_n$ is

$F_{X_n}(t)\rightarrow F_X(t)$